# Perl regex question

Tags: regex, perl

How can I match and store the various lines in this string in $1 , $2 and $3 variables in Perl?

```
$string = "This is a line 1.\nThis is line 2.\nThis is line 3.\n";
```

I know I have to use the /m modifier but so far my attempts have been unsuccessful.

I tried

```
$string =~ m/^(.*?)$.^(.*?)$.^(.*?)$/sm;
```

and other combinations to no avail. I want to keep it simple, so any answers pointing out mistakes would be helpful. I want to only try and use /s and /m modifiers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found it. `$.` being treated as a variable was the clue. I used:

```
$string =~ m/^(.*?)$(.)^(.*?)$(.)^(.*?)$/sm;
```

and printed `$1`, `$3`, `$5`.

Thanks all.

Comment: This is not a solution.  You should not have been trying to use `$` to match the newlines in the first place.  It's a zero-width assertion; it matches the empty string right *before* the newline.

Comment: @abc: Somebody already said that. Yeah, either way, `"\n" =~ /$(?:.)/sm;` or `"\n" =~ /(?:$)./sm;`, the `'.'` will only match a newline (in a non-capture way). But, as @Alan More says, its not really a solution, its more an observation.

Comment: You might want to change (.) to (?:.) throughout, to avoid capturing groups which you don't care about.  Still advise to use the idiomatic code posted earlier, rather than this particular obsession.

Answer (score 6):

Why use `$` and `^` to match the intermediate newlines at all? It would be simpler to do

```
$string =~ m/^(.*)\n(.*)\n(.*)/ ;
```

with neither /m nor /s. Or even simply

```
($a,$b,$c) = split /\n/,$string ;
```

Comment: If you are positive its only 3 lines, why do you need the `^ and \n?$` ? If you are not positive, then the `\n?$` part won't match `some\n word \n here \n `

Comment: True dat. Answer corrected to match the first 3 lines and ignore the rest, so it matches (more or less) what the split solution does.

Comment: I want to see /m /s in action while solving this.

Comment: @abc: Why do you insist on using `/m` and `/s`?  They're just getting in the way.

Answer (score 4):

What's going on is `$.` is parsed as a variable (its one of those special ones; line number in input file):

```
$. = "foo";
print "matched" if ("foo" =~ m/$./);
```

A workaround is using some more syntax to force parsing `$` as a regex with `(?:$)`. But that's ugly. I'd just match the new line directly (or use split):

```
$string =~ m/^(.*)\n(.*)\n(.*)$/;
```

Answer (score 2):

I fixed your regexp:

```
$string =~ m/^(.*?)\n(.*?)\n(.*?)$/sm;
```

'$.' was threated as variable (warnings with `use warnings; use strict;`)

BTW - assining them to an array:

```
my @list = $string =~ m/^(.*?)\n(.*?)\n(.*?)$/sm;
```

Comment: `%list` is not a list, but a hash.

Comment: I'm not so sure what affect mixing `/sm` will have with this regex. Hypothetically, it would match `"\n\n\nA\nB\n\nC\nD\nE"` wouldn't it?

Comment: Well, I think `^$` using `/m` modifier will match `\n` in the middle of the string as well. Try printing out list in: `@list = "\n\n\nA\nB\n\nC\nD\nE" =~ /^(.*?)\n(.*?)\n(.*?)$(.*)/sm;` Secondly, `/s` modifier will match `\n` in your regex if your quantifiers were greedy. In this case, neither `/sm` is really needed.

Comment: @sln is right. /m causes ^ and $ to match every embedded newline.

Comment: From the docs: `Used together, as /ms, they let the "." match any character whatsoever, while still allowing "^" and "$" to match, respectively, just after and just before newlines within the string.`

Comment: you are right, fixed, as for /sm it was just left from original regex

Answer (score 1):

```
my ( $first_line, $second_line, $third_line, $rest_if_any ) 
    = split( /\n/m, $string, 4 )
    ;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the variables `$1`, `$2`, and `$3`, you can do this by creating a regex string that doesn't see `$.` as a variable.

```
my $string = "This is a line 1.\nThis is line 2.\nThis is line 3.\n";
my $rex = q/^(.*?)$.^(.*?)$.^(.*?)$/; #The . between $ and ^ is the newline
$string =~ m/$rex/sm;
```

To show that this is correct, you can use `Data::Dumper`.

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper($1,$2,$3);
```

This will output:

```
$VAR1 = 'This is a line 1.';
$VAR2 = 'This is line 2.';
$VAR3 = 'This is line 3.';
```

To go one step further and show that the . between $ and ^ is matching the newline, you can add the following:

```
$rex = q/^(.*?)$(.)^(.*?)$(.)^(.*?)$(.)/;
$string =~ m/$rex/sm;

print Dumper($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6);
```

This will output:

```
$VAR1 = 'This is a line 1.';
$VAR2 = '
';
$VAR3 = 'This is line 2.';
$VAR4 = '
';
$VAR5 = 'This is line 3.';
$VAR6 = '
';
```